# Creating a client-server chat program

Tags: java, client, chat, objectinputstream

In a server client chat program using object streams how would i be able to send a message to all clients and a private msg to certain clients?

in my listening for connections method i accept the connection

```
public void listenForConnections()
{
    String sUserName="";

    try{
        do {
            System.out.println("Waiting on connections");
            Socket client = servSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Connection From: " + client.getInetAddress());          


            //pass message handling to thread and listen
            ClientHandler handler = new ClientHandler(client,this);
            handler.start();//As usual, this method calls run.                

        } while (true);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then i pass this client to a thread in the server to handle message exhanges;

i,e;

> ```
>             //pass message handling to thread and listen
>             ClientHandler handler = new ClientHandler(client,this);
>             handler.start();//As usual, this method calls run.
> ```

How and where do i keep a list of connected clients?

i thought of a hastable with the key being the username and ObjectOutPutStream.  And to then read object being sent after the connection was accepted but i ran into problems. The message was a login command giving the username and a command LOGIN

My code became;

> System.out.println("Waiting on connections");
>                   Socket client = servSocket.accept();
>                   System.out.println("Connection From: " + client.getInetAddress());
>
> ```
>             ObjectOutputStream clientOOS = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
>
>             outputStreams.put(sUserName, oos );
>
>
>             //big problem here
>             //serializeation
>             /*ois = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
>             oos = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
>
>             //ask for the username /authenticate
>             System.out.println("SERVER: getting username");
>             myMessage inMessageLogin = (myMessage) ois.readObject();
>
>             if(inMessageLogin.getCOMMAND()==ServerCommands.CMD_LOGIN)
>             {
>                 sUserName=inMessageLogin.getsUserName();
>                 System.out.println("SERVED User " + sUserName + " connected.");
>                 //save stream
>                 outputStreams.put(sUserName, oos );
>                 //oos.close();
>                 //oos.flush();
>                 //ois.close();
>                 ois=null;
>                 //oos=null;
>             }
> ```

```
            //end of problem!!!!!*/
```

Which i commented out as it gave errors about corrupted streams, any ideas?

Thanks

To send a message to the server from client;

> ```
> //default cmd is to send to all
> public void sendMessage(String sText,int iCommand)
> {
>     System.out.println("sendMessage");
>
>     outMessage=new myMessage();
>
>     outMessage.setsUserName(sCurrentUser);
>     //set command
>     outMessage.setCOMMAND(iCommand);
>
>     outMessage.setsMessage(sText);
>
>     System.out.println("send msg" + outMessage.displayMessage());
>
>     try {
>         oos.writeObject(outMessage);
>         oos.flush();
>         oos.reset();
>         //clear up send message from txbox
>         txtMessage.setText("");
>     } catch (IOException ex) {
>         Logger.getLogger(myClientGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,
> ```
>
> ex);
>           }
>       }

client code to connect to server;

> ```
> public void connectToServer()
> {
>     String sServer=txtServer.getText();
>     PORT=Integer.parseInt(txtPort.getText());
>     try {
>         //host = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");//InetAddress.getLocalHost();
>         host = InetAddress.getByName(sServer);
>         clientSocket = new Socket(host, PORT);
>     }
>     catch (Exception e){
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
> }
>
> public boolean createStreams()
> {
>     try{
>         //serial
>         //*******************************************************************************
>         // open I/O streams for objects - serialization streams
>         oos = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
>         ois = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
>
>
>
>         return true;
>     }
>     catch(Exception e)
>     {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>         return false;
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: I guess, you need to provide client code which writes command to network.

Comment: i posted my send method from client

Comment: How do you create client connection and ObjectOutputStream in client's code -- can you post this client's code as well?

Comment: is your `myMessage` class implements `Serializable`? If yes, are all it's fields are `Serializable` too?

Comment: And does your server have `myMessage` class in it's classpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code works perfectly well for me. Note that Server class must have access to Message class in it's classpath and that Message class implements `Serializable`.

Client:

```
class Client {
    private Socket clientSocket;

    public void connectToServer()
    {
        String sServer="localhost";
        int PORT = 8181;
        try {
            InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName(sServer);
            clientSocket = new Socket(host, PORT);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void sendMessage(String sText,int iCommand) throws IOException {
        Message outMessage = new Message();

        outMessage.setCOMMAND(iCommand);
        outMessage.setsMessage(sText);

        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        try {
            oos.writeObject(outMessage);
            oos.flush();
            oos.reset();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client c = new Client();
        c.connectToServer();
        try {
            c.sendMessage("test message", 42);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class Message implements Serializable {
    private int iCommand;
    private String sText;

    public void setCOMMAND(int iCommand) {
        this.iCommand = iCommand;
    }

    public void setsMessage(String sText) {
        this.sText = sText;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Message{" +
                "iCommand=" + iCommand +
                ", sText='" + sText + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Server:

```
class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8181);

        do {
            Socket s = serverSocket.accept();
            try {
                processClient(s);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } while (true);
    }

    private static void processClient(Socket s) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        Message message = (Message) ois.readObject();
        System.out.println(message.toString());
    }
}
```